# Alias mkdir to print verbose output on Mac

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
$ type mkdir
$ mkdir is aliased to `command mkdir -p -v'
$ mkdir folder
$ mkdir folder
$ mkdir folder
$ unalias mkdir
$ type mkdir
mkdir is hashed (/bin/mkdir)
$ mkdir folder
mkdir: folder: File exists
```

Why aliased version does not print verbose output ?

Comment: In my experience `mkdir` doesn't print anything if the directory already exists and `-p` is used. Probably because this means that nothing is done, and `mkdir` only seems to print when a directory is actually created. This, of course, has nothing to do with aliases.

Comment: You should start reading the manual pages of utilities you use when you have questions. They offer a wealth of precise information and would have answered this question. Try `man mkdir`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the `-p` option in the alias if you want to see the folder already created message. Try the following

```
mkdir folder
alias mkdir="mkdir -v"
mkdir folder
```

and you will see the error message. If you use this

```
mkdir folder
alias mkdir="mkdir -p -v"
mkdir folder
```

You won't see it because that's how the `-p` option works.

Why does it work like this? If we assume that `-p` actually gave an error when it encountered folders that had already been created what would it do with deeply nested folders where it's creating them and then reusing the same folder which it just created to create the next one, should it throw an error. If it did it would create a lot of errors in scripts.

If you got to hear and think... **`but why can't it just throw the error on the last directory ie if it sees that the one it's about to create exists, not the ones prior`**... Please think long and hard about that :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Can you explain me how did you find the answer ? or is just experience ? I did not find info like this in man mkdir